# How to allow guest to make entry without login

Tags: authentication, guest

I have a pretty simple form. I just realized that it doesn't work unless I'm logged in as admin.

Is there a way to bypass that, or to simply turn off authentication altogether for Craft CMS? For this project, I think that would be fine.

Any ideas? I'd prefer to not use a plugin.

Here is the form:

```
        {% for entry in craft.entries.section('ScoreRequest').limit(1).find() %}
            <form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/saveEntry">
            <input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="{{ entry.sectionId }}">
                    <div class="request-form">
                <div>
                  <input class="form-field" placeholder="Your Name" id="title" type="text" name="title">
                </div>
                <div>
                  <textarea class="form-field-2" placeholder="Your Email Address" id="body" name="fields[email]"></textarea>
                </div>
                        <div>
                            <textarea class="form-field-2" placeholder="Your Phone Number" id="body" name="fields[phone]"></textarea>
                        </div>
                <div>
                  <textarea class="form-field-2" placeholder="Your Company" id="body" name="fields[body]"></textarea>
                </div>
                    </div>
            <input class="form-button" type="submit" value="Send">
            </form>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi cheechaw, and welcome to the Craft CMS Stack Exchange! Insane was correct: your previous answer was actually a comment, and if Brad's answer was helpful it'd be best to accept it. I've removed your previous answer so you don't collect any more downvotes, and to keep things tidy for others that find their way here.

Answer (score 6):

The [Guest Entries](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries) plugin is made for this scenario!